# How to show first message on form load and next one after 1min?

Tags: javascript

As I don't have much knowledge of javascript and I need your help. My problem is like this:

I am using setInterval() for increasing the value of `i` every after 1 minutes and I am using this code:

```
var i = minutes;
function decrementMin() {
    if(i>=0)
    {
        i--;
    }
    if(i==0)
    {
        alert('Minute = Congratulation your time begin now!');
    }                         
    document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = i + "minutes";
}
setInterval('decrementMin()',60000);
```

The problem is I want to show first message in `<div id='minutes'></div>` when page loads, but it shows the message after 1 minutes interval. If there is something that I am missing in my code please let me know.

Comment: **Never** pass a string to `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`. Doing so is as bad as using `eval()` and it results in unreadable and possibly insecure code as soon as you use variables since you need to insert them into the string instead of passing the actual variable. The proper solution is `setInterval(function() { /* your code *) }, msecs);`. The same applies to `setTimeout()`. If you just want to call a single function without any arguments, you can also pass the function name directly: `setInterval(someFunction, msecs);` (note that there are **no** `()` behind the function name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are setting the interval before the first message is displayed.  Instead, you can call the function straight away and then set the interval.  Also, you need to clear the interval once you've reached 0:

```
var i = minutes;
var intID;
function decrementMin() {
    if(i>=0)
    {
        i--;
    }
    if(i==0)
    {
        clearInterval(intID);
        alert('Minute = Congratulations my friend your time begins now!');
    }
    document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = i + "minutes";
}

decrementMin();
intID = setInterval(decrementMin, 60000);
```

This way you call your function straight away, and then set it to run every minute. Once you reach 0, you clear the interval so that the function doesn't count to "-1", etc.